# when i connect lightsail plesk panel this is give me error

Tags: filezilla

when i connect plesk panel eith filezilla this is give me always error
Disconnected from server
Status: Connecting to 44.194.246.170:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Plain FTP is insecure. Please switch to FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PORT 192,168,29,176,196,199
Response:   200 PORT command successful
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing

give me answer what is problem beacause i use lightsail plesk panel